# ramprate % /min rate limiter in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, rate-limiting

how to  implement running % /min in simulink ?
I need to limit the Pwr (kw) output to 5%/min using a rate transition block.
Im  using the dynamic rate limiter block as follows but the calculation of %/5 minute maybe wrong. Please help[image]

Comment: why would you think it is wrong?

Comment: because the rate limiter block computes per sample time and i want to compute per min

Comment: that's why you should have added the rate transition, no? you wrote you used it but it is not visible. If so, what did you test to see that it is sampling at the wrong time?